Eliminate items from multiple element arrays based on partial matches to another array
Given the JSON below, I am struggling for a jq query that will eliminate any items in places[].fThings[] or places.sThings[] that are not a partial string match to any of the strings found in toDo[].  It should be noted not all places will have fThings or sThings present.  While it most likely be one or the other, both or neither could be present.
The output should be the same as the input with the non-matching *Things items filtered out. Empty arrays are fine to return.
I've tried a great many combinations of map(select(any(index(...)))) as well as contains but I'm tripping over my own feet with Cannot index or Cannot iterate errors and fear I have missed something obvious.
{
  "places": [
    {
      "location": "wapc1",
      "type": "pcs,cstrl,refdoc",
      "fGroup": "cert-apc-1",
      "fThings": [
        "pcs_app#2.1#bp",
        "pcs_app#2.0#bp",
        "pcs_app#2.1#bp",
        "pcs_app#2.1#cc",
        "pcs_app#2.1#ex_acct",
        "pcs_app#2.1#repr"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wapc2",
      "type": "pcs,cstrl",
      "fGroup": "cert-apc-2",
      "fThings": [
        "pcs_app#2.1#mts",
        "pcs_app#2.1#mts",
        "pcs_app#2.1#mta",
        "pcs_app#2.1#mtr",
        "pcs_app#2.1#mop",
        "pcs_app#2.1#mor",
        "pcs_app#2.1#mov"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wapc3",
      "type": "pcs,prx,cstrl",
      "fGroup": "cert-apc-3",
      "fThings": [
        "pcs_app#2.1#d2c",
        "pcs_app#2.1#ci",
        "pcs_app#2.1#co",
        "pcs_app#2.1#gr",
        "pcs_app#2.1#repr",
        "pcs_app#2.1#refr",
        "pcs_app#2.1#gf",
        "pcs_app#2.1#dq"
      ],
      "aThings": [
        "prx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wapc4",
      "type": "pcs,prx,cstrl",
      "fGroup": "cert-apc-4",
      "fThings": [
        "pcs_app#2.1#mtr",
        "pcs_app#2.1#mtstat",
        "pcs_app#2.1#mop"
      ],
      "aThings": [
        "prx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc1",
      "type": "bsrv",
      "sGroup": [
        "cert-bs-1"
      ],
      "sThings": [
        "ci_svc#1.35.0",
        "config_svc#1",
        "erec_svc#1.27",
        "hm_svc#1.34.0",
        "ri_svc#1.0.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc2",
      "type": "bsrv",
      "sGroup": [
        "cert-bs-2"
      ],
      "sThings": [
        "erec_svc#1.27",
        "profile_svc#1.7",
        "mor_svc#1.33.0",
        "mta_svc#1.31.0",
        "mtr_svc#1.39.0",
        "mtstat_svc#1.35.0",
        "ri_svc#1.0.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc3",
      "type": "bsrv,r-bsrv",
      "sGroup": [
        "cert-bs-3",
        "cert-rs"
      ],
      "sThings": [
        "co_svc#1.36.0",
        "d2c_svc#1.34.0",
        "erec_svc#1.27",
        "gr_svc#1.19.0",
        "profile_svc#1.7",
        "config_svc#1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc4",
      "type": "bsrv,r-bsrv",
      "sGroup": [
        "cert-bs-4",
        "cert-rs"
      ],
      "sThings": [
        "erec_svc#1.27",
        "profile_svc#1.7",
        "mtstat_svc#1.35.0",
        "config_svc#1",
        "bp_svc#1.46"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "toDo": [
    "bp_svc#1.46##1.46.0-2410.0-03",
    "config_svc#1##1.12-2410.0-05",
    "erec_svc#1.27##1.27-2410.0-03",
    "pcs_app#2.1#bp##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#ci##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#co##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#cc##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#dq##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#d2c##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#df##2.1-2410.0-05"
  ]
}


Save the toDo array for reference, iterate over the target items, and update them with |= using select with inside to filter for containedness:
. as {$toDo}
| (.places[].["fThings", "sThings"] | arrays[]) |= select(inside($toDo[]))

{
  "places": [
    {
      "location": "wapc1",
      "type": "pcs,cstrl,refdoc",
      "fGroup": "cert-apc-1",
      "fThings": [
        "pcs_app#2.1#bp",
        "pcs_app#2.1#bp",
        "pcs_app#2.1#cc"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wapc2",
      "type": "pcs,cstrl",
      "fGroup": "cert-apc-2",
      "fThings": []
    },
    {
      "location": "wapc3",
      "type": "pcs,prx,cstrl",
      "fGroup": "cert-apc-3",
      "fThings": [
        "pcs_app#2.1#d2c",
        "pcs_app#2.1#ci",
        "pcs_app#2.1#co",
        "pcs_app#2.1#dq"
      ],
      "aThings": [
        "prx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wapc4",
      "type": "pcs,prx,cstrl",
      "fGroup": "cert-apc-4",
      "fThings": [],
      "aThings": [
        "prx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc1",
      "type": "bsrv",
      "sGroup": [
        "cert-bs-1"
      ],
      "sThings": [
        "config_svc#1",
        "erec_svc#1.27"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc2",
      "type": "bsrv",
      "sGroup": [
        "cert-bs-2"
      ],
      "sThings": [
        "erec_svc#1.27"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc3",
      "type": "bsrv,r-bsrv",
      "sGroup": [
        "cert-bs-3",
        "cert-rs"
      ],
      "sThings": [
        "erec_svc#1.27",
        "config_svc#1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "location": "wwc4",
      "type": "bsrv,r-bsrv",
      "sGroup": [
        "cert-bs-4",
        "cert-rs"
      ],
      "sThings": [
        "erec_svc#1.27",
        "config_svc#1",
        "bp_svc#1.46"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "toDo": [
    "bp_svc#1.46##1.46.0-2410.0-03",
    "config_svc#1##1.12-2410.0-05",
    "erec_svc#1.27##1.27-2410.0-03",
    "pcs_app#2.1#bp##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#ci##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#co##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#cc##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#dq##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#d2c##2.1-2410.0-05",
    "pcs_app#2.1#df##2.1-2410.0-05"
  ]
}

Demo

AHA, inside!  As Michael Jordan said you miss 100% of the jq keywords you don't know.   Same goes for citing multiple elements in an array of names.  And inverting it all by starting with toDo instead of ending with it.  Brilliant!
Gratitude aside, how does the symbolic binding of the entire document as $toDo make this all work?  I would have thought .toDo[] would have had to be referenced directly at some point.  The . is not .toDo[]but it magically seems to be in this case.

"Destructuring" is explained here: "Just as {foo} is a handy way of writing {foo: .foo}, so {$foo} is a handy way of writing {foo: $foo}. Multiple variables may be declared using a single as expression by providing a pattern that matches the structure of the input." So . as {$toDo} is the same as . as {toDo: $toDo} which can be read as .toDo as $toDo.
